# MYSQL database confusion

Tags: select, key

So on this question, I'm having trouble.
    EMPLOYEE(fname,minit,lname,ssn,birthdate,address,sex,salary,superssn,dno) key:ssn
    DEPARTMENT(dname,dnumber,mgrssn,mgrstartdate) key:dnumber
    PROJECT(pname,pnumber,plocation,dnum) key:pnumber

Here is what I wrote:

```
Select e.ssn, e.lname,e.fname,
From employee e,
where e.ssn in
(select s.ssn, s.lname,sfname
    from employee s,
    where s.superssn = e.ssn, AND s.lnamme='Wallace' s.fname ='Jennifer'
)
```

But I only got 10 out of 15 points, my professor said my select s.ssn,slname part is wrong, and it must "match my e.ssn". How should I fix this?

Comment: you mean the typo in lnamme ? use the alias `s.` throughout all of it, even in select stmt

Comment: You have a nice processor.  I would be considerably less generous, because you have an `IN` subquery that is returning more columns than you are checking.  (The typos for commas and missing `and` are incorrect but less important.)

Comment: just do a join, not a subquery. So it would be a self-join, with 2 aliases

Comment: @drew can you please write an answer and I will accept it. sorry the typo was not the problem I just typed it wrong on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IN` is fine, but with a correlated subquery, `EXISTS` is the way to go:

```
Select s.ssn, s.lname, s.fname
From employee s
where exists (select 1
              from employee e
              where e.superssn = s.ssn AND
                    e.lname = 'Wallace' AND
                    e.fname = 'Jennifer'
             );
```

Note:

- The `s` and `e` are swapped.  You want the *supervisor* information, so it goes in the outer query.
- The extraneous commas have been removed.
- `AND` has been added.

Using `IN`, it looks like:

```
Select s.ssn, s.lname, s.fname
From employee s
where s.ssn IN (select e.superssn
                from employee e
                where e.lname = 'Wallace' AND
                      e.fname = 'Jennifer'
               );
```

Note that the correlation clause is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

A self-join (same table). Alias `e` is for the worker, alias `s` is for the supervisor.

```
select s.ssn, s.lname,s.fname,
From employee s
join employee e
on s.ssn=e.superssn
where e.lname='Wallace' and e.fname ='Jennifer'
```

Answer (score 1):

your in statement is going to make this query slow. you can refactor it to be a self join like so

```
select e.ssn, e.lname, e.fname
from employee e
join employee s on s.superssn = e.ssn
where s.lnamme='Wallace' AND s.fname ='Jennifer';
```

the problem with your in statement is you are making a dependent subquery which checks every row in the employee table with every row in the same table.

to break down the query itself

```
select s.ssn, s.lname, s.fname -- s is the supervisor
from employee e -- e is jennifer
join employee s on s.superssn = e.ssn -- self join on the supervisors id is equal to the employees id
where e.lnamme='Wallace' AND e.fname ='Jennifer';
```

Comment: just lose a few of the commas John

Comment: @Drew yep was in the process of doing that :) +1 on yours, same thought process which improves the answer drastically